# Android Studio keeps renaming modules

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

At some point recently, Android Studio has started renaming my modules.

For instance, module "app" gets renamed to "project-app", and my existing project/app.iml file gets changed to project/project-app.iml. It also messes with my project tree in Android Studio, where the existing "app" module is now no longer expandable, but the new "project-app" is.

This wouldn't be so bad if then at some point Android Studio didn't decide to add *another* "prefix-" to the front, of the grandparent folder name.

It gets worse for nested folders, where project/folder/module.iml gets renamed to project/folder/project-folder-module.iml and the corresponding module in Android Studio to "project-folder-module".

And then upon loading, I get a bunch of errors popping up about nonexistent modules.

I can fix it (temporarily) by editing .idea/modules.xml to remove the unwanted modules and return things to the original state (and rename the .iml files in the filesystem, removing the compounded prefixes). But overall this is irritating and I'd like to find out why it's happening and how to stop it.